# Can I legally publish screenshots from Linux apps on my website?

Tags: legal, linux

I am planning to open a blog webpage, publish technology-based content on it in Turkish language, maybe in English language later, and make money via blogger earning methods like Google AdSense.

*In this blog, for example, I'll post:*

1. What is DNS?
2. What is DHCP Server?
3. What is Network Policy Server?
4. What is File Server Resource Manager?
5. What is Firewall?

I want my posts have screenshots and/or videos. That's why, for example, I'll describe the DNS, and enrich the post in conjunction with DNS Server installation and configurations for the first post, or I'll redirect the user to another page of my blog with a link for installation and configurations.

Due to screenshots and videos are problematic for Microsoft products such as Windows Server 2016 and Windows 10 without activation, for the third or fourth post, I won't add screenshots or videos as long as I don't meet equivalents of them in Linux distributions, they will just have descriptions.

I thought that I can use Linux distributions for this purpose. However, firstly, I want to be sure whether this kind of usage is legal or not for Linux distributions like Ubuntu, CentOS, and Kali Linux.

**EDIT:** I live in Turkey

Comment: Are you based in Turkey some other country?  The country may change which laws you have to follow.

Answer (score 2):

Yes or no :P

It depends on a few things, [this article](https://tinytake.com/screen-capture-copyright-violation-or-fair-use/) outlines some

I think the takeaway is this quote from the very end of the article "*It’s likely that if you are using a screen capture of copyrighted works to educate, comment, or criticize the topic the use of screen capture images are aptly deemed fair use. It generally comes down to money. If you are going to profit from the use of a screen capture image, you may be in violation of fair use.*"